# Number format SQL INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table where a column has the format `NUMBER(2,3)`.
I try to insert the value **5.73** but it doesn't work.

The error is :

```
ORA-01438 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
          that exceeded the precision defined for the column.*
```

I read the documentation but i don't understand the scale.

So, what is the format accepted value 0-99 with 3 values ​​after the decimal point ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding precision and scale.  You have a number with a precision of 2.  That means that there are two significant digits.  It has a scale of 3, which means that these are to the right of the decimal point.

So, your column can represent values between 0.000 and 0.099

What you want is `NUMERIC(5, 3)`.  "precision - scale" is the number of digits to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

This has come from here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832

> Optionally, you can also specify a precision (total number of digits) and scale (number of >digits to the right of the decimal point):
>
> column_name NUMBER (precision, scale)

So in your example you are allowed a total number of 2 digits ( and 3 digits to the right of the decimal point). Which doesn't work for 5.73, perhaps you need a type of number(3,2) which would allow 3 digits 2 of which can be right of the decimal point.